# Imitate MFC the Mechanism of Dynamic foundation

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

When i learn `MFC`,, I want to imitate some mechanism, here, i just want to imitate MFC's the Mechanism of dynamic to create object Simple..Can you point out where is the fault, and how to finish it . Thank you...

```
class Object;
struct classRuntime 
{
    Object* pBasedClass;
    Object* pNextClass;
    char* className;
    Object* CreateClass();
};

class Object
{
public:
    static struct classRuntime ObjectClassRuntime;
    Object() {
        cout<<"Object constructor"<<endl;
    }
    static Object* CreateObject() {
        return new Object;
    }
};

 classRuntime Object::ObjectClassRuntime = {NULL, NULL, "Object", 
                                                          Object::CreateObject};
```

[image]

Comment: What problem do you have? What error? What is not working?

Comment: there is lots of errors.. this is just my thought.. i don't know how to Organizes them..

Comment: Then show us the errors or a nice and complete example to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You should write `&Object::CreateObject`. VC++ is not as strict as other compilers, and will sometimes overlook the missing `&`.

Comment: @MSalters: According to yours suggestion, it will show the error C2078: too many initializers. my platform is VC6.0... thank you ..

Comment: @Tu_JianWu: I just got an email from Microsoft about Visual Studio 11, the successor to 2001/2005/2008/2010. Apparently they no longer think it's necessary to point out that [we've entered the 21st century](http://xkcd.com/354).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Object;

struct ClassRuntime {
    Object*   basedClass;
    Object*   nextClass;
    char*     className;
    Object* (*instanceFactory)();
};

class Object
{
public:
    static const ClassRuntime ObjectClassRuntime;
    Object() {}
    static Object* CreateInstance() { return new Object; }
};
const ClassRuntime Object::ObjectClassRuntime = {NULL, NULL, "Object", Object::CreateInstance};

class Toto : public Object
{
public:
    static const ClassRuntime TotoClassRuntime;
    Toto() {}
    static Object* CreateInstance() { return new Toto; }
};
const ClassRuntime Toto::TotoClassRuntime = {NULL, NULL, "Toto", Toto::CreateInstance};
```

Comment: Thanks for help... in my book, there is 'Object* CreateObject();' not 'Object* (*CreateObject)();' can you explain it ? it is a mistake ?  i had updated the question with picture..

Comment: Not a mistake, just a difference in the naming. Your example has `CObject* (PASCAL *m_pfnCreateObject)`. The `PASCAL` is an holdover from 16 bits Windows (you can safely ignore it) and the `m_pfn` is an abbreviation for "member, pointer to function". Otherwise it's the same.

Comment: There is CObject* (PASCAL* m_pfnCreateObject()); on CRuntimeClass which is similar to my Object* (*CreateObject)(); declaration.

I guess CRuntimeClass::CreateObject implementation is just a call to m_pfnCreateObject